# Html layout with content height 100% and separate toolbar

Tags: html, css, layout, height, scrollbar

I need to create a layout that has a toolbar, a (variable height) tab line, a content view and an info view. The entire content must always fill the entire browser window, without causing a scrollbar to appear. Only the content and info panels can have scrollbars, and only when they overflow. [My layout so far](http://jsfiddle.net/manisto/URvNA/4/) seems to be working in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer. I can't use absolute positions, because the tab line can vary in height, and I would really like to avoid using JavaScript for layout.

Right now I have this markup:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="toolbar">toolbar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tabs">
            <td colspan="2" class="tabs">tabs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="content">
                <div>content content content content</div>
            </td>
            <td class="info">info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

And this css:

```
html, body, body > table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body > table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
body > table > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.toolbar { background-color: red; }
.tabs { background-color: green; }
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.content > div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.info {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 300px;
}
```

It must look like this:

[image: Intended layout]

Comment: Why are you using a table layout? Nowadays the 'standard' is to use <div> elements, which gives some more flexibility and more predictable behaviour.

Comment: I tried out tables because I couldn't get <div /> elements to work either, though I would much prefer them. But using tables, I got closer to an actual result that I ever did with <div />s.

Answer (score 0):

### Try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URvNA/5/)

Its more complicated than a regular table layout using CSS, but should work for you with some tweaking.

HTML

```
<div class='viewport'>
    <div class='caption'>
        <div class='toolbar'>toolbar</div>
        <div class='tabs'>tabs</div>
    </div>   
    <div class='row'>    
        <div class='content'>content</div>
        <div class='info'>info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, .viewport{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.viewport{
    display:table;    
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
.caption{
    display: table-caption;
}
.content, .info{
    display:table-cell;
}
.toolbar{
    background:red;
}
.tabs{
    background:green;
}
.content{
    background:blue;
}
.info{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Because it renders exactly like my example (because everything displays as a table element), it has the exact same problem, in that it only adds scrollbars to the content and info panels in Chrome. Do you have any idea how to fix that?